# Imageview constrained to bottom of toolbar filling toolbar

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

Im using a constraint layout with an imageview inside it and I constain the top of the imageview to the bottom of the toolbar, I want the image to fill the rest of the screen though depending on screen size, so I set the imageviews hieght and width to math-parent and also scaleType=fitXY. 
The problem I have is that even though it is constrained to the bottom of the toolbar it fills the toolbar as well.

Here is my code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/rain_drops"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<!--android:alpha="0.5"/>-->





<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no way to do so unless you change the `android:layout_height` to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

if you want to keep the `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` use `layout_marginTop` with the exact height of your toolbar.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/rain_drops"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the margin top method as you said worked great!